# Writing a Makefile rule, for a SINGLE target with MULTIPLE dependacies

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

For Eg., if I were to compile bunch of files in a hardware description language, I can write a Makefile in the following way

```
    analyze: a.v b.v c.v top.v
        vcs $(OPTIONS) a.v
        vcs $(OPTIONS) b.v
        vcs $(OPTIONS) c.v
        vcs $(OPTIONS) top.v
```

Make analyze, will compile all the files in its dependency & builds the final executable. How can I write a "SINGLE Makefile rule", which will compile all its dependencies and build an executable - Mimicking the above with a rule SOMETHING LIKE:

```
    analyze: %.v
        vcs $(OPTIONS) %.v
```

The above works for a single file dependency. But, if I have multiple file dependencies how will I handle the multiples files ? Can I use a "for loop" for all the dependencies. I was looking for Makefile options to access the "dependency files" to be used in a for loop, but COULD NOT find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dummy stamp target for each to-be-analyzed file:

```
analyze : a.analyzed-stamp b.analyzed-stamp c.analyzed-stamp top.analyzed-stamp

%.analyzed-stamp : %.v
    vcs $(OPTIONS) $<
    touch $@
```

Comment: The above solution works, but also creates *.analyzed-stamp files. Instead, is there any other elegant solution in Makefile, where a "for loop" loops automatically all the dependent file in the target and builds final executable. The reason is I have about 900 design (*.v) files and that many "*.analyzed-stamp" files floods the Makefile run directory

Comment: Adding an action for analyze target "rm *.analyzed-stamp" will clean up the dir. For knowledge sake, still wondering whether there is any special variable supported by make, helps a "for loop" to traverse all the dependencies of a target.

Comment: @Mike: `make` doesn't operate very well on low-level commands like looping. Of course, you could simply do a `for file in $^; do vcs $(OPTIONS) $$file; done` in the command section. However, this would re-analyze every file every time, and it's often better to reify a process as a file and avoid repetition.