# Makefile: compiling several objects with single target

Tags: object, makefile

I have several c++ objects that I'd like to compile using a single target. If possible I'll make a variable in the makefile that list all the object files and then have a single target that compiles them all.

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822591/writing-a-makefile-rule-for-a-single-target-with-multiple-dependacies) I have the following "Makefile" so far:

```
#### Directories and flags

ifndef $(DIR_MAIN)
  DIR_MAIN=../..
endif

DIR_EXE=$(DIR_MAIN)
DIR_SRC=$(DIR_MAIN)/src/Analyse_MC
DIR_MISC_SRC=$(DIR_MAIN)/src/Misc
DIR_BLD=$(DIR_MAIN)/build/Analyse_MC
DIR_MISC_BLD=$(DIR_MAIN)/build/Misc
COMP=g++

COMPILE_FLAGS= -std=c++11 -O3 -lstdc++ `pkg-config --cflags eigen3` -msse2 -I${DIR_MISC_SRC}
LINK_FLAGS= -O3 -fopenmp -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -lhdf5_cpp -lhdf5

OBSERVABLE_OBJECTS=g_decomp_IP_orthog_sphere.o g_decomp_LS_orthog_sphere.o g_decomp_IP_disk.o g_decomp_LS_disk.o find_rank.o eigenvectors.o GramSchmidt.o diagonal_Hamiltonian.o mean_log_WF.o energy.o JK_EP_overlap.o overlap.o geo_mean_eigstate_overlap.o eigstate_overlap.o pair_corr_bins.o


#### Compile all

all: setup observables $(DIR_EXE)/Analyse_MC

setup:
    @mkdir -p $(DIR_BLD)

#### Compile observable objects

observables: $(addsuffix -stamp,$(OBSERVABLE_OBJECTS))

%.-stamp : %.o
    ${COMP} -c -o $@ $<
```

However when running `make` I get the following:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `g_decomp_IP_orthog_sphere.o-stamp', needed by `observables'.  Stop.
```

So I've misunderstood something.

If possible I'd also like each of the objects to be updated with changes in `.h`-files with the name of the object in addition to some common `.h`-files for all of the objects. Is this possible?

Or do I have to / is it recommended to write a separate target for each object?

EDIT:

Some info about the variables:

DIR_MAIN is defined the way it is because usually this makefile will be called from another makefile which defines DIR_MAIN from its directory using `pwd`; but ut can also be called on its own from its own directory.

DIR_MISC_SRC points to some header files necessary for the files in DIR_SRC.

DIR_BLD and DIR_MISC_BLD will contain the corresponding resulting object files.

Comment: Your makefile is confusing, what are those `stamp` files for? I'm not even sure what use they have in the question you linked. Why do they depend on the object file but then in the recipe you attempt to compile `.o` files into `.-stamp` files?

Comment: As I wrote it is based on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822591/writing-a-makefile-rule-for-a-single-target-with-multiple-dependacies, which answers a similar question to mine

Comment: Neither that question nor yours attempt to explain what the stamp files are for, the reason I'm asking is as I far as I can tell they aren't needed.

Comment: I'm not sure why they're needed apart from it might do what I need. If you have a way to do what I need without them write it as an answer and I'll accept if it works

Comment: Please post a dump of your source tree with something like `tree`, it's not clear why `DIR_MAIN` is defined the way it is and you haven't provided any info of what's in each dir. Is `-I${DIR_MISC_SRC}` there because the files in `DIR_SRC` include those headers?

Comment: Edited in some info. I didn't show the source tree because this is part of a big project with lots of files and folders (I'm restructuring / cleaning up the folder structure and makefiles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message does show you what you've done wrong, but a bit obliquely:

> make: *** No rule to make target `g_decomp_IP_orthog_sphere.o-stamp`, needed by `observables`.  Stop.

Your rule to make stamp files is:

```
%.-stamp: %.o
```

You probably wanted that to be

```
%.o-stamp: %.o
```

---

Compiling `%.o` to `%.o-stamp` looks very strange to begin with - probably you just want

```
observables: $(OBSERVABLE_OBJECTS)
.PHONY: observables
```

Stamp files are sometimes useful for actions you want to perform once but have no output file. For compilation, the object file is the output file, and that's all that make requires.

---

> If possible I'd also like each of the objects to be updated with changes in `.h`-files with the name of the object in addition to some common `.h`-files for all of the objects. Is this possible?

That's a whole nother question in itself - you want to search for "makefile auto-dependency generation" for starting points.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I'm not sure what the stamp thing is; what I would like is to have a single target compile a set of object files, instead of writing a bunch of almost identical targets. The question I linked to seemed to suggest I can do it this way with stamps. Is there a better way? Or is it recommended to have a bunch of individual targets instead?